# Web Dev: How to write a website specification doc?

Tags: documentation, specifications

I'm writing a specification document for my website (it's a school project, btw). I currently have some proze about the overall layout and theme of the website, how you navigate through the website, and a brief description of the contents. I however do not have a list of all pages; should I include that?

Also, how can I determine the technical specifications for my website? I know, for example, that I need PHP 5 (or compatible), but I'm not sure what version of HTML, CSS and JavaScript to ask for. How can I determine these requirements?

Comment: Also check out example specifications, like this one : http://www.vordweb.co.uk/example_website_specification.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that the list of each page would be included in the Navigation section of your document. Also to determine which version you HTML, CSS, and Javascript might I suggest using a blanket "Use of standards compliant HTML, CSS, and Javascript which will render in all major browsers". Or something similar. You don't necessarily need to pidgin-hole yourself into using a specific format as long as it does what you want in the browsers you want.I think a good requirements doc would steer away from making decisions like this for the developer and stick to decisions such as what the content looks like, what the navigation map is, what content to provide, and functionality.

As an example of what standards there are for HTML, if you want your page to ["validate" as a particular HTML standard](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/doctype.html) then you would want to indicate that version in the  header but the header itself is unnecessary for the browser except to tell it to render in standards or quirks mode. For a "standards" mode site use of the HTML 5 doc type  [is all that you need](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/).

Answer (score 0):

The HTML version can be found in the first DOCTYPE tag, usually on the first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

In this case, it's XHTML 1.0 Transitional.
As for CSS, most browsers use version 2, but it's trivial unless you're using some crazy new CSS features slated for the next release. For javascript, according to the wikipedia page, the latest version is 1.8.2. This again doesn't really matter that much, differences between Javascript versions are usually extremely minor.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a technical spec.

Answer the following questions.

1) What is your site for? What purpose does it serve?

2) Who is the site made for, do they buy into the answer to question 1?

3) The audience from question 2... what type of computers / devices will they access the website from?

From answering these questions you will know the minimum requirements that you have to design for. For instance, if everyone you are marketing to is older with ancient hardware (develop in straight HTML no javascript, use tables for layout) ;) If you are aiming for a younger, computer savvy audience, develop using HTML5, CSS3, jQuery.

Server side tech doesn't make a difference unless you are trying to create a site at scale. (to support millions of users)

I would include a sitemap (list of pages)